# How to read BertForMaskedLM with BertModel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have fine-tuned BertForMaskedLM and now I want to read it with BertModel. But my saved model looks like this:

```
BertForMaskedLM(
  (bert): BertModel(
    (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
      (word_embeddings): Embedding(119547, 768, padding_idx=0)
      (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
      (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
      (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
..................
```

How to read it with transformers BertModel?

Comment: Can you provide more details? How do you save the model? If you save the model in the standard Huggingface way (not directly in PyTorch), you should be able to load all `BertFor*` models from the directory.

Comment: @Jindřich i save it with save_pretrained

Comment: @Jindřich but however after i save it and then read it with BertModel it performs very poorly. Should I change there something?

Comment: How do you read the model file you saved? Normally, you need to create an object from the model class you train and load your own weight files into this object. You can do this with load_state_dict. If you can share your model class I will try to help more.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, I tried to give a solution. First, I must ensure that my BertForMaskedLM is saved in the following form:

```
self.model.save_pretrained('bert_mlm_source')
```

Second, when loading the trained model, we just need to take the parameters of Bert layer out of BertForMaskedLM as:

```
self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(self.cfg.bert_source)
self.mlm_bert = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(self.cfg.bert_mlm_source)
self.bert.embeddings = self.mlm_bert.bert.embeddings
self.bert.encoder = self.mlm_bert.bert.encoder
```

In the end, I just need to use 'self.bert' for the appropriate downstream tasks. This can be done because BertForMaskedLM simply adds a layer of BertOnlyMLMHead on last of Bert, and the key layers in the middle are the same.

There may be a more convenient and beautiful way, if you have found it, please let me know. Thank you very much.